# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i try to make a "Service" which helps me with some small tasks,

my NavigationService.js has following function:

```js
    redirectView = (view) => {
        this.props.history.push(`/${view}`)
    }
```

and then i got my Welcome.jsx which has :

```js
<BtnRectangularBorder>
    <BtnRectangular className="battle-shonen-color btn-rectangular-md-size btn-rectangular-primary" title="Cards Overview" onClick={NavigationService.redirectView("/cards-overview")} />
</BtnRectangularBorder>
```

so now in my .js file it gives me an error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined" ,

should i do the .js file a Component or anything since in doenst recognize the history

Comment: Is `NavigationService` a React component?  Does it get props?  When are you instantiating it?  It sounds like this is just a utility class, which wouldn't have props.  That is why the `this.props` is undefined.  Since props are not defined, you can't access the history attribute.  I presume you are trying to use React Router?  More information is needed here.

Comment: Can you share your NavigationService.js code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) for your routing solution.  I'm not certain how useful it would be to wrap a utility function around it, as it is already a utility function.  However, if you would like to do so you would need to expose the current `history` object to the function.  Something like this:

```
const NavigationService = {
  redirectView = (history, view) => {
    history.push(`/${view}`)
  }
}
```

```
const MyComponent = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <BtnRectangularBorder>
    <BtnRectangular 
      className="battle-shonen-color btn-rectangular-md-size btn-rectangular-primary" 
      title="Cards Overview" 
      onClick={NavigationService.redirectView(history, "/cards-overview")} 
    />
  </BtnRectangularBorder>
));
```

Usually I'm all about wrapping things in utilities, but I'm honestly not sure what it buys you in this case.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey there, thanks! i want not to have to write for every button a function to redirect in ea. component, thats why i wanted a "universal" function for that

Comment: Another comment sry for that, thanks alot your solution work BUT i did change it again since i researched how to handle it cuz you said its already a "utility function", Thanks alot!